# Setter of a lambda function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, setter

Consider the following dumb example :

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        template <class Function> 
        inline double f(double x, Function&& function)
        {
            return function(x);
        }
};
```

With this class, I can call `MyClass::f(x, function)`, with a lambda function to execute it on `x`, with (I hope) no overhead. My question is : what would be the equivalent with the `function` as a settable member of the `MyClass` ?

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        inline double f(double x)
        {
            return _function(x);
        }
    // What are the setter and the type of the protected member _function ?
};
```

Comment: It could be anything that takes a single double and returns a double. You could use `std::function<double(double)>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lambda functions (as well as some other types of "callable" functions) can be wrapped and stored using the [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) template class, found in the `<functional>` header. Its template parameter is a function signature with the syntax

```
ReturnType(ArgumentType1, ArgumentType2, ...)
```

so in your case the whole function wrapper type becomes

```
std::function<double(double)>
```

and thus, your code becomes

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        inline double f(double x)
        {
            return _function(x);
        }
        void setFunction(std::function<double(double)> && f)
        {
            _function = f;
        }
    private:
        std::function<double(double)> _function;
};
```

`std::function` is "more" than a wrapper for function pointers. As you might know, lambda functions can capture part of the variable context, which needs to be stored somewhere. `std::function` does this for you transparently.

Note that `std::function` does not support overloaded signatures / templated call operators for functors. When assigning a functor with a call-operator signature like `T operator()(T value)` to a `std::function<double(double)>`, it can only be called with this signature. So there is no `std::function<T(T)>` (unless `T` is already known, such as a template parameter of your class).

---

An alternative which might be more efficient in some cases (you need to benchmark / profile it), is to make your whole class a template class with the function type parameter being the template parameter. Then you can store a function as a member:

```
template<typename Function>
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(Function && f) :
            _function(f)
        {}
        inline double f(double x)
        {
            return _function(x);
        }
    private:
        Function _function;
};
```

In order to create such an object, you need to specify the template parameter, like this:

```
auto myLambda = [](double x){ return x * 0.25; };
MyClass<decltype(myLambda)> myObject { myLambda };
```

To avoid this ugly syntactic overhead, add a "maker" function which takes advantage of template type deduction:

```
template<typename Function>
auto makeMyClass(Function && f) -> MyClass<Function> {
    return MyClass<Function>(f);
}
```

Then, the code becomes more readable, with use of `auto` again:

```
auto myLambda = [](double x){ return x * 0.25; };
auto myObject = makeMyClass(myLambda);
```

Comment: I like your templated class method. I will benchmark all of this and post the results later.

Comment: A quick benchmark of 1 billion calls of a basic function which takes 3 double and return a double (g++ -O3) tell me that there is no practical difference between a direct call and my "dumb" example at the beginning. With a class member using std::function or your templated class trick, there is approximately a 15% time overhead.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to use an `std::function` wrapper, possibly letting the constructor initialize it from an input callable object:

```
#include <functional> // <== REQUIRED FOR std::function

class MyClass
{
    public:

        template<typename F>
        MyClass(F&& f) : _function(std::forward<F>(f)) { }

        inline double f(double x)
        {
            return _function(x);
        }

    private:

        std::function<double(double)> _function;    
};
```

Notice, that this may bring you some run-time overhead, but the design is simple and flexible. Unless you can prove this run-time overhead is a bottleneck for your software's performance requirements, this run-time overhead should not be a concern.

Comment: I will need to benchmark that, because this is for intensive computations with probably hundreds of millions of calls.

Comment: @Vincent: Indeed, in that case you should benchmark it. If what you are passing is a function pointer or a non-capturing lambda (which can be converted to a function pointer), and your implementation is clever enough, it is likely that the overhead will be minimum. But well, when it comes to performance, one should never trust assumptions which are not backed by concrete measurements.

Comment: @Vincent I added an alternative solution to my answer, you might want to check it out.